# How to compare two different div ids or class values in xpath?

Tags: xpathnavigator

```
  <div class="productColor">
         <ul id="morecolor" class="morecolors">
  </div>
  <div class="sizeofproduct">
  <div class="prices">
```

Here, I need to compare `div class="productColor"` and `div class="prices"`
both `div` are different, so how to compare this using firepath xpath?

Comment: Finally i got the answer,please use below xpath:

Comment: //*[@class='productColor'] and div[@class='prices']